# Custom font on UINavigationBar not working

Tags: ios, swift2, uinavigationbar

I have no idea why this is not working, I've tried it with many valid strings (cFont = "Courier" by the way but I've tried "Chalkduster" and a few others to test), the colors right above are working but the font is not. Any ideas?

Function is right below the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in AppDelegate.

```
func setUpAppearance() {

//Work fine

    window?.tintColor = Colors().navBackgroundColor

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Colors().navBackgroundColor
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = Colors().navTextColor

//Doesn't work

    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: cFont, size: 24)!]

}
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Didn't realize I had to add a separate instance for the bar button items as well as NSForeGroundColorAttributeName.

Updated function works fine...

```
func setUpAppearance() {

    window?.tintColor = Colors().navBackgroundColor

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Colors().navBackgroundColor
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = Colors().navTextColor

    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: cFont, size: 24)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Colors().navTextColor]

    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: cFont, size: 24)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Colors().navTextColor], forState: .Normal)

}
```